# Bookmarklet doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

I've written a script that changes the CSS elements on a badly designed page. I was testing it in Chrome as I went along, and now it's fully functional. I've placed it on the web and am now using this as the bookmarklet text:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://myexamplewebsite.com/files/adjustPage.js';})();
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, but doesn't work in the latest Firefox or IE. I've looked in the error consoles of Chrome and Firefox and neither one complains of any issues. Firefox also doesn't react when I put the code in the 'code' field of the error console and evaluate.

Firefox does say in the little status bar at the bottom: "Read myexamplewebsite.com", but nothing else.

It isn't a quirk in the bookmarklet code I'm running above, because I've placed a 'hello world' script on the same server and it worked fine.

Is there a better way to work out what Firefox/IE don't like about my script?

If you're interested, the code I'm running is here. Please excuse the ugliness of the code, it was a very quick and dirty hack:

```
var section = document.getElementsByClassName('cqGroupBox');
for(var i in section) {
var children = section[i].childNodes;

for(var j in children){
    if(children[j].innerText == 'Detected on configuration') {
        var style = section[i].getAttribute('style');
        style += ' display:none;';
        section[i].setAttribute('style', style);
        break;
    }
}
}

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for(var i in tables) {
try{
    var styleNode = tables[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
    var style = styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(style == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if(style.match('top: 434px; left: 120px;')
    || style.match('top: 461px; left: 120px;')
    || style.match('top: 434px; left: 456px;')
    || style.match('top: 461px; left: 456px;')){
        style += ' display:none;';
        tables[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style').firstChild.nodeValue = style;
    }
} catch(err){continue;}
}


var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for(var i in labels) {
try{
    var styleNode = labels[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
    var style = styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(style == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if(labels[i].innerText == 'OS'
    || labels[i].innerText == 'App. Server'
    || labels[i].innerText == 'DBMS'
    || labels[i].innerText == 'Web Server'){
        style += ' display:none;';
        labels[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style').firstChild.nodeValue = style;
    }
} catch(err){continue;}
}

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i in divs) {
try {
    var styleNode = divs[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
    var style = styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(style == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if(style.match('top: 291px; left: 23px;')){
        style.replace('height: 109px;','');
        divs[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style').firstChild.nodeValue = style;

        innerDivs = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var j in innerDivs){
            try {
                innerStyle = innerDivs[j].attributes.getNamedItem('style').firstChild.nodeValue;
                if(innerStyle.match('width: 665px; height: 109px;')){
                    innerStyle = innerStyle.replace('height: 109px;','');
                    innerStyle += ' font-size: 130%';
                    innerDivs[j].attributes.getNamedItem('style').firstChild.nodeValue = innerStyle;
                }
            } catch(err){continue;}
        }
    }
} catch(err){continue;}
}
```

Comment: seems fine, but maybe it does not match your checks ;) maybe this is the computed style and not the one that the html plage serves :) we need the page where this script should be fired

Comment: Good point. I saw that the dimensions on the page were all absolute and assumed they would have been hardcoded (the page is _that_ bad). I can't share the page because it's a proprietary system (ClearQuest bug tracking system), but do you have any suggestions for what I can look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerText` is a nonstandard property (so far; there are now efforts to create a standard for it) which is not supported in Gecko. Does using `textContent` instead fix things for you?

Comment: This has certainly led me in the right direction. When I made this change, the first of the four loops worked in FF, which is a good indication that I'm using code that is Chrome-specific. I'll keep looking into what else is different to fix my script. Do you know of any easy way to look this up?

Comment: @HXCaine A good start would be looking at the error console in Firefox to see what exceptions are getting thrown, if any... of course that won't help if the script catches all exceptions silently.  Another option is to put alerts in the script to see if you can pin down what the first line that's not reached is and then see what comes right before it.

Comment: I have noticed that the main issue with this script is the assignment of values to fields. For example, `tables[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style').firstChild.nodeValue = style` does not change the value of `nodeValue`. 

I realise that this is not the original question, but I don't want to make a new one for the same problem. Do you know why the assignment doesn't work in Firefox?

Comment: Probably because this is relying on Attr nodes, which are generally not well supported in browsers and about to be removed from the DOM.  Why isn't this code just using setAttribute?

Comment: I eventually fixed the compatibility by using setAttribute. My problem was essentially figuring out what methods/fields were available to me given the non-standard nature of JS, but I looked it up on the Gecko DOM pages and found what I needed. I've posted the fixed code below for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code, that works on Chrome, Firefox 3.6 and the latest Firefox (as of Aug 2011).

```
var section = document.getElementsByClassName('cqGroupBox');
for(var i in section) {
var children = section[i].childNodes;

for(var j in children){
    if(children[j].textContent == 'Detected on configuration') {
        var style = section[i].getAttribute('style');
        style += ' display:none;';
        section[i].setAttribute('style', style);
        break;
    }
}
}

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for(var i in tables) {
try{
    var styleNode = tables[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
    var style = styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(style == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if(style.match('top: 434px; left: 120px;')
    || style.match('top: 461px; left: 120px;')
    || style.match('top: 434px; left: 456px;')
    || style.match('top: 461px; left: 456px;')){
        style += ' display:none;';
        styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue = style;
        tables[i].setAttribute('style', style);
    }
} catch(err){continue;}
}


var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for(var i in labels) {
try{
    var styleNode = labels[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
    var style = styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(style == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if(labels[i].textContent == 'OS'
    || labels[i].textContent == 'App. Server'
    || labels[i].textContent == 'DBMS'
    || labels[i].textContent == 'Web Server'){
        style += ' display:none;';
        styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue = style;
        labels[i].setAttribute('style', style);
    }
} catch(err){continue;}
}

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i in divs) {
try {
    var styleNode = divs[i].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
    var style = styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(style == null) {
        continue;
    }

    if(style.match('top: 291px; left: 23px;')){
        style = style.replace('height: 109px;','');
        styleNode.firstChild.nodeValue = style;
        divs[i].setAttribute('style', style);

        innerDivs = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var j in innerDivs){
            try {
                innerStyleNode =  innerDivs[j].attributes.getNamedItem('style');
                                    innerStyle = innerStyleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

                                    if(innerStyle == null) {
                            continue;
                            }

                                    if(innerStyle.match('width: 665px;')
                                        && innerStyle.match(' height: 109px;')){
                    innerStyle = innerStyle.replace('height: 109px;','');
                    innerStyle += ' font-size: 130%';
                    innerDivs[j].setAttribute('style', innerStyle);
                }
            } catch(err){continue;}
        }
    }
} catch(err){continue;}
}
```

See the Gecko DOM if you're having issues finding out what's available for use, etc.